# Is it possible to call a URL without a visible view?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to load a URL without a visible view?

Basically I'm trying to submit some information to my server by a php page. It works from my webViewController, which has a working view, but not from my appDelegate, which doesn't have a visible view.

Comment: yes, see NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) to submit the information to your php page.

Comment: Thank you Julio. I tried that and got a bunch of Duplicate Symbols I didn't know how to fix, but the NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection was all I needed. Thanks for your help.